# Why are my cookies containing JSON occasionally malformed

Tags: json, cookies

We're using a cookie for some non-sensitive convenience data about our site visitors. We emit three values:
1) creation date (in ticks),
2) user data, JSON serialized,
3) validation hash

We're seeing a fair number of requests coming in with only half a cookie. They contain the full date and truncated user data, something like {"Foo":false,"Bar":0

This is a high-volume site, and the number of bad cookies looks to be about 1-3 per minute (out of 8-10 thousand page requests per minute).

Anyone experience anything similar? I'm wondering if we have a browser that doesn't like the JSON, or maybe the header is getting truncated by some browsers, or maybe there's a JSON serializer bug. We're using the JavaScriptSerializer in .NET 3.5.

Comment: Is there any correlation between the user agent string and the bad cookies?

Does the JavaScriptSerializer generate proper JSON or just serialized javascript? JSON.org does not list it as a JSON library.

Comment: We are not getting user agent data correlated with the error log. Big source of frustration right now.

Comment: for future reference: if you are asking about why a cookie might be malformed, it might make sense to include a few examples of the header as you issue it and as it is coming back. And your title needs some work. just sayin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unencoded embedded commas and over stuffed cookies are the typical causes of this behavior

Comment: Makes good sense - JSON generates commas, and we are not currently encoding the result. I am going to look at encoding the JSON data and get back to you.

Comment: Added url encoding - won't know for sure until the change makes it to production and experiences our normal load, but the header certainly looks "righter".

Comment: @stuart - yeah, seems pretty obvious to me. also, you need to be really really aware of how big your cookies are and how many cookies you have because cookie overflow is a silent killer. lol...

Comment: I didn't encode the entire cookie, and saw an interesting side effect as a result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342253/do-some-browsers-encode-cookies