# Have you found any bugs in Native JSON implementations?

Tags: json

What bugs, if any, have you found in the current batch of native JSON implementations?

FYI - this is meant to be a sort of central repo of native json bugs.

The reason I feel this is important is that the de-facto standard, json2.js, does not install itself if it finds a native implementation, so it is crucial to identify native bugs so that you can decide whether to force json2 to overwrite native if a bug affects your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has a JavaScript implementation of JSON.stringify, instead of a native one, so it's actually slower than the JS one on JSON.org (although handles more edge cases).

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=22718

Comment: @Annie, Nice catch. I would like to keep this question open for a while to see if it gets some love but you will get the check.

Answer (score 1):

[IE8 native JSON.parse bug causes stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288962/ie8-native-json-parse-bug-causes-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 3.6 ignores the replacer return value in stringify.

[bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=548462)

[test page](http://skysanders.net/Tests/NativeJSONTests/JSON.tests.htm)

[180 browser/platform combinations confirm bug](http://www.browsercam.com/public.aspx?proj_id=508872)