# How can I send null value?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to do something like this

```
$.get('/Controller/Action/', { model : null }, function(data) {});
```

Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. In server side the value of the model is `{object}`.

How do I get `null`?

**EDIT**

--- Javascript ---

```
var json = JSON.stringify({ model: null });
$.get('/Controller/Action/', json, function (data) { });
```

--- Controller ---

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test(object model) 
{ 
// here i need model = null but keep returning {object}
return PartialView("TestPartial"); 
}
```

Comment: You are not sending JSON to the server. `{ model : null }` would serialize to `model=` before sending, which would be interpreted as a empty string. If you want to send real JSON, you need to stringify it first.

Comment: please look in my comment at the answer below

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling to understand exactly what you asking so I'm going to try and attempt it. :)

If you just want to send no value then just set the data to null

```
$.get('/Controller/Action/', null, function(data) {});
```

If you want to have one parameter of the action null then just exclude it from the data array.

Eg, for this action:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Foo(string bar, string foo)
{
    /*The Magic*/
}
```

you might only want to send a value for `bar` and not `foo`, then the jquery would be:

```
$.get('/Controller/Foo/', { bar: 'It's a bingo! }, function(data) {});
```

This will result in `bar` being the passed value and `foo` being null.

Another thing to note, to avoid JSON Hijacking, ASP.NET MVC 2 is designed for JSON to be passed as from a `POST` request rather than a `GET`.

The reason can be found here: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx

To make this change, decorate your Action with the `[HttpPost]` attribute and change your jQuery to:

```
$.post('/Controller/Foo/', { bar: 'It's a bingo! }, function(data) {});
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**
I just thought/discovered something. Instead of passing `{ model: null }` try passing `{ model: undefined }`.I just had a similar issue where I wanted to pass nothing back to a string parameter and 'null' gave a string of `"null"` where as `undefined` gave `null`.

Comment: thanks for your answer...
$.get('/Controller/Action/', null, function(data) {});
it doesn't work cuz the return of model keep {object}

Comment: can you add your action signature to your original question?

Comment: Ok, after a quick test I can see what the issue is and I can't seem to see a way around it. It could be a bug in the default model binder but I doubt it.

If you know the type of the model being passed back, strongly type it, it should fix this issue. Apologies I don't have a resolution for you.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts, I tried what you said and works with parameter of type string, so the parameter is object then keep receiving null...
I think that is a bug of the model binder as you said... I'm trying to solve this issue and if I reach the goal I'll keep you aware.. thanks Alastair

Comment: @Kim, Doh! I was hoping we'd managed to snare it :( Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('/Controller/Action/', '{ "model" : null }', function(data) {});
```

As others have said, you can't let jQuery do your serialization in this case.

You will need to do it manually or with [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), which is always my recommendation. I NEVER rely on jQuery or native implementations as there are just too many inconsistencies and bugs.

Comment: thanks for your answer

i'm trying to do something like that

--- Javascript ---

var json = JSON.stringify({ model: null });
$.get('/Controller/Action/', json, function (data) { });

--- Controller ---

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test(object model) {
    // something
    return PartialView("TestPartial");
}

--

and don't work, idk what i'm doing wrong
the result of model of controller keep {object}

Comment: Why not rely on native implementations? Every native JavaScript implementation I've seen so far is fully compliant with the json2.js API.

Comment: @Eli - no, you just think that they are ;-O And the problem with bugs in native JSON implementations is that they are always going to be out there forcing you to check for that browser/version in order to make sure that you force an overwrite of the faulty implementation. Browsers do not fade quickly - how long do you think  you will have to support FF 3.0-3.6? That's how long you would have to use your own JSON.

Comment: Care to provide an example of a browser with a faulty native JSON implementation, including said fault?

Comment: @Eli - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343820/have-you-found-any-bugs-in-native-json-implementations